# Blue-Green Deployment on AWS using ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-delivery, blue-green-deployment

I need help in order to achieve Blue-Green Deployment.

What I have in My Bucket -

1. One Blue Environment hosted on ElasticBeanStalk.
2. One Green Environment hosted on ElasticBeanStalk.
3. Both Environments are getting created by CF-Template.Both are having their own ELB.

What I am looking for -

1. I need to switch traffic from Blue to green.
2. First I need to know which Environment is currently live so that I can plan my app deployment to next Environment.
3. Once I knew my current Environment(Blue in this case) , I deployed my app to Green-Environment and now this Environment is ready to accept the traffic.
4. I need to migrate 25% traffic to Green and do a health check, If health check is okay I will add another 25% and do a health check and so-on.
5. At any point if health check fails , I should be able to route entire traffic back to Blue Environment.

I need to implement this solution in my CI-CD Job. My CI job is creating my package and deploying this to S3. My CD job is provision the Infrastructure (ElasticBeanStalk) and 
uploading the package to newly created Environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control deployment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk like that, since it involves having two live environments and doing a cname swap. Not exactly what your'e trying to achieve but something close it is called [Immudatable Deployments which are available out of the box](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentmgmt-updates-immutable.html).

From the documentaion:

> To perform an immutable environment update, Elastic Beanstalk creates
>   a second, temporary Auto Scaling group behind your environment's load
>   balancer to contain the new instances. First, Elastic Beanstalk
>   launches a single instance with the new configuration in the new
>   group. This instance serves traffic alongside all of the instances in
>   the original Auto Scaling group that are running the previous
>   configuration.
>
> When the first instance passes health checks, Elastic Beanstalk
>   launches additional instances with the new configuration, matching the
>   number of instances running in the original Auto Scaling group. When
>   all of the new instances pass health checks, Elastic Beanstalk
>   transfers them to the original Auto Scaling group, and terminates the
>   temporary Auto Scaling group and old instances.